# Angular change text-color as you type

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myNumber">

$scope.$watch('myNumber', function(nV, oV) {
 $scope.myNumberPlus10 = (nV + 10);  
});

<span>{{ myNumberPlus10 }}</span>
```

I'd like to change the `<span>{{ myNumberPlus10 }}</span>` text color to green as I type a number into the `<input>`, but once I'm done typing, I'd like the color to revert back to the original text color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-focus and ng-blur directives on your input and use an ng-style on your span; ng-focus and ng-blur can set a variable to true or false depending on whether the input field is in focus while the span's ng-style will watch that variable and determine whether to turn the font green.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myNumber" ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false">

$scope.$watch('myNumber', function(nV, oV) {
 $scope.myNumberPlus10 = (nV + 10);  
});

<span ng-style="{focus: 'color:green'}">{{ myNumberPlus10 }}</span>
```

or ng-class with some css class setting the color to green ('green-text' in the example below):

```
<span ng-class="{'green-text':focus}">{{ myNumberPlus10 }}</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated this in my question...I need it to happen as the user types in the input. I'm experimenting with $timeout, which is looking promising. I will post a solution if I can figure one out :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the :focus CSS selector, this has nothing to do with Angular, no need to overcomplicate things:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myNumber = 0;
    $scope.$watch('myNumber', function(nV, oV) {
      $scope.myNumberPlus10 = (nV + 10);
    })
  })
```

```css
input:focus + span {color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="myNumber" />
  <span>{{myNumberPlus10}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout){
   var timeout;
    $scope.myNumber = null;
    $scope.myNumberPlus10 = null;
    $scope.style = {color: 'red'};
    
    $scope.keyPressed = function () {
     var myNumber = parseInt($scope.myNumber,10);
      if (timeout) {
        $timeout.cancel(timeout);
      }
      timeout = $timeout(function (){
       $scope.style = {color: 'red'};
      }, 1000); 
      $scope.style = {color: 'green'};
      $scope.myNumberPlus10 = isNaN(myNumber) ? null : myNumber + 10;
    }
    
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="myNumber" ng-keyup="keyPressed()">
<span ng-style="style">{{myNumberPlus10}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```